# MongoDB - trying to transfer contents of an entire collection to one 'user object' in another collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collections, transfer

I've been collecting records for myself for some time now, so I have one collection entirely of my own records. Now I'm trying to add multi user capability and want to transfer all my data from that collection to an array within my own user object in another collection.

This is where I'm at.

```
myRecordsCollection.find({}).forEach(function(err, doc) {
    usersCollection.update(
        {
            "name": "Me"
        },
        {$push:
            {
                'records' : doc
            }
        }
    );
});
```

But this doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

$push push only one item at a time,But you are trying to push array,You need  to use $each with $push.

```
myRecordsCollection.find({}).forEach(function(err, doc) {
    usersCollection.update(
        {
            "name": "Me"
        },
        {$push:
            {
                'records' : { $each: doc }
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: It seemed to work, right until the ?end? of the documents, which is when this occurs. D=

`c:\Users\Jon\Desktop\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });`

Comment: May be size of  your doc big thats why this error is coming.....another option to iterate over doc, you can use async.each